# Postgres Decimal value calculation with json POST

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, operators

I have some issues around precision, and I am not sure how to solve it. In my Postgres database, I have prices in `DECIMAL(8,2)`. When I pull down a set of prices, I sum them and then compare them with the sum of two user submitted prices `0.55` and `5.02` given to me through a json POST.

The issue is that in my calculation, I should be comparing say 5.57 to 5.57, but instead I am comparing `if(POST_CALC === SERVER_CALC)` or `if(2.011.011.001.000.55 === 5.569999999999999)`, and that is obviously failing.

It seems like my data from Postgres is coming back as a string and that may deal with the decimal setting of `DECIMAL(8,2)`... but if I change my query value on the Node.js server to a `Number(value_here)` then I end up comparing `5.569999999999999` to `5.569999999999999` which is great and all that it works, but I am worried that in another situation I may not be so lucky and things will hit the bucket.

In the scenario where you are comparing numerical values from Postgres AND user input, what is the best strategy to correctly compare calculated values?? I have a feeling that this may be with keeping my values as `DECIMAL(8,2)`?

Comment: Life becomes easier in JS if you store currency values as an integer in the smallest unit you require, normally cents. Then format it to dollars on output. I'm not sure how to map this to/from postgres DECIMAL.

Comment: Sequelize does [DECIMAL as strings](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4893) and will support [arbitrary conversion in 4.0](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6290)